# Cannot overwrite village what should I do?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Hi I want to transfer my clash from ios to android but when I typed code after it I  see this message cannot overwrite village what should I do? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried deleting all data, start the village fresh *then* try the code? It could also that you've already used the village link feature and that it hasn't updated [on your iOS' side]?

Answer (score -1):

If you have bought gems in the past or you're over a Town Hall level of 4 you can not transfer a village to a new phone. I hope that this helps. I personally think that this is a dumb decision on SS' part but its worth noting this if you are to make a new account in the future.

Comment: I think that is simply not true, unless you find a link to prove me wrong. This is more related to the "iOS/Android migration". Although, personal opinion and "hope that it helps" do not belong in an Answer in Arqade. Win a bit more reputation and you will be able to comment posts !